# How to show that $[(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r] \Rightarrow [p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)]$

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

To show that $[(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r] \Rightarrow [p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)]$ without using a truth table. That is, using logical laws.

Comment: **Hint:** Try using a truth table.

Comment: @anakhronizein. Sorry, can you tell me another way not using a truth table?

Comment: Why is one of your arrows a $\Rightarrow$ and the others are $\rightarrow$? Do they all mean the same?

Answer (score 1):

With *Natural Deduction* :

1) $(p→q)→r$ --- premise

2) $q$ --- assumed [a]

3) $p→q$ --- from 2) by $\to$-introduction

4) $r$ --- from 1) and 3) by $\to$-elimination

5) $q \to r$ --- from 2) and 4) by $\to$-introduction, discharfging [a]

6) $p \to (q \to r)$ --- from 5) by $\to$-introduction

> $[(p→q)→r] \vdash [p \to (q \to r)]$ --- from 1) and 6).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $p \Rightarrow q \equiv \neg p \vee q$.