# Proving a logical implication using modus ponens and metatheorems

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

Using the law of inference the axiomatic system and metatheorems prove that

$${(\neg A > B),(A > C),(B > D)} \vdash (\neg C > D)$$ Where > is 'implies' and ~ negation.
I know how to use the Laws of Logic to prove logical equivalent, but no idea about logical implication.

Another question i have is using all logic laws to this impication legit?Whats the steps (a general understanding for solving this)?

Comment: Use [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) on $(A \to C)$ to derive $(\lnot C \to \lnot A)$. Then use [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism#Propositional_logic).

Comment: The only rule i can use is modus ponens (along with the axiomatic system and the metatheorems), so i can't use the other rules of inference

Comment: What axioms ? What metatheorems ? Hypo syll is a "metatheorem" easily proved at the start of the development.

Comment: Well think it like this, i can use logic laws and the modus ponens without any other.

Comment: If "logic laws" mean axioms, what axioms ?

Comment: I am refering to those http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-laws-of-propositional-logic

Comment: If so, you have to remove $\to$ with equiv $(P \to Q) \Leftrightarrow (\lnot P \lor Q)$.

Comment: Can you be a bit more thorough?

Comment: See example : [How to prove a logical implication?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351204/how-to-prove-a-logical-implication)

Comment: In a nutshell, the table of logical laws you have linked does not contain $\to$; thus, no way to prove your formula with them. You have : either to replace $\to$ (see comment above) or use [axioms for $\to$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems#Implication_and_negation).